# in dc.js, row chart small bars are difficult to click on

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

In a row chart, if the bars are very small, it´s sometimes really hard to find the few pixels in which to click to perform a filtering. Is there a way to allow for a click in a larger surface? Maybe clicking on the bar titles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug. There is a commit that was supposed to make row labels clickable, and a comment that it doesn't work, here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/commit/9c3b58fa80389cafe255791b4eef652ea5a485bd#commitcomment-7555642